# Есть ли разница в способах задания массива?

Tags: java

Эти две строки эквивалентны, или есть разница?

```
String[] dirNames = new String[] {"Dir_A","Dir_B","Dir_C","Dir_D","Dir_E"};
String[] dirNames = {"Dir_A","Dir_B","Dir_C","Dir_D","Dir_E"};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3)

> An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for
> all its components.

> Инициализатор массива создаёт массив и задаёт начальные значения для всех его компонентов.

разницы между этими двумя строками не будет

Answer (score 3):

Давайте скомпилируем

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] dirNames = new String[] {"Dir_A","Dir_B","Dir_C","Dir_D","Dir_E"};
        String[] dirNames1 = {"Dir_A","Dir_B","Dir_C","Dir_D","Dir_E"};
    }
}
```

И посмотрим скомпилированный байт код

```
public class Main {
    public Main() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] var10000 = new String[]{"Dir_A", "Dir_B", "Dir_C", "Dir_D", "Dir_E"};
        var10000 = new String[]{"Dir_A", "Dir_B", "Dir_C", "Dir_D", "Dir_E"};
    }
}
```

Разницы нет, компилятор просто сам подставит определение